# multiple variables to single dimensional array vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, solidworks

I can't figure out how to get multiple coordinates into a single dimensional array in VBA to use later. Here's the part of the code where I'm adding values to a coordinate array. I couldn't figure out how to add the x,y,z data to a single dimensional array. I've tried different methods but cannot get multiple values to show even as a string.

The goal of this code is to use coordinate data to feed into another function by passing a coordinate array. In this section of code I am acquiring the coordinate data from a sketch with the vLines function that holds 6,7,8 as x,y,z data. I want to hold all of this x,y,z data in the CoordinatesArray which I'm going to access later. Should I really use another array for the xyz data or a string? What would be a good method for accessing or should I make a 4D array with coordinate number and the three positions later?

I want the coordinates array to be

coordinate(1) = x1, y1, z1

coordinate(2) = x2, y2, z2

coordinate(n) = xn, yn, zn

```
For i = 0 To NumLines - 1
        coordx1 = (vLines(12 * i + 6))
        coordy1 = (vLines(12 * i + 7))
        coordz1 = (vLines(12 * i + 8))
        CoordinatesArray(i) = coordx1 & "" & coordy1
        'CoordinatesArray(i) = CStr(coordx1) & CStr(coordy1) & CStr(coordz1)
        Debug.Print "Coordinate Array = "; CoordinatesArray(i)
        Debug.Print "  Line(" & i & ")"
        Debug.Print "    Start = (" & vLines(12 * i + 6) * 1000# & "," & vLines(12 * i + 7) * 1000# & "," & vLines(12 * i + 8) * 1000# & ") mm"
        Debug.Print "    End   = (" & vLines(12 * i + 9) * 1000# & "," & vLines(12 * i + 10) * 1000# & "," & vLines(12 * i + 11) * 1000# & ") mm"
    Next i
```

Comment: Perhaps `coordinate(1) = array(x1, y1, z1)`.

Answer (score 2):

As a "jagged array" (an array of arrays)

```
For i = 0 To NumLines - 1
        coordx1 = (vLines(12 * i + 6))
        coordy1 = (vLines(12 * i + 7))
        coordz1 = (vLines(12 * i + 8))

        CoordinatesArray(i) = Array(coordx1, coordy1, coordz1)
Next i
```

To access:

```
Debug.Print CoordinatesArray(5)(0) 'x
Debug.Print CoordinatesArray(5)(1) 'y
Debug.Print CoordinatesArray(5)(2) 'z
```

As a 2-D array

```
Redim CoordinatesArray(1 to NumLines, 1 to 3) 

For i = 0 To NumLines - 1
        coordx1 = (vLines(12 * i + 6))
        coordy1 = (vLines(12 * i + 7))
        coordz1 = (vLines(12 * i + 8))

        CoordinatesArray(i, 1) = coordx1
        CoordinatesArray(i, 2) = coordy1
        CoordinatesArray(i, 3) = coordz1
Next i
```

To access:

```
Debug.Print CoordinatesArray(5, 1) 'x
Debug.Print CoordinatesArray(5, 2) 'y
Debug.Print CoordinatesArray(5, 3) 'z
```

Or you could create a custom Type or Class with fields x, y and z and create an array of those.